# Generate fields using environment variables and insert them into object

Tags: json, environment-variables, jq

I have below JSON where in I need to add key and values at a specific place from env variable. Moreover would try to avoid any hardcoding in JSON if possible

Sample JSON:

```
{
    "abc": {
        "admin": {
            "username": "admin",
            "password": "pa55word",
            "tenant_name": "t1"
        },
        "users": [
            {
                "username": "n1",
                "password": "password",
                "user_domain_name": "Default",
                "project_name": "p1",
                "project_domain_name": "Default"
            },
            {
                "username": "n2",
                "password": "password",
                "user_domain_name": "Default",
                "project_name": "p2",
                "project_domain_name": "Default"
            }
        ]       
    }
}
```

Output json needs to be like below where in `$AUTH` and `$REG` are env variables.

```
{
    "abc": {
        "auth_url": "$AUTH",
        "region_name": "$REG",
        "endpoint_type": "PRIVATE",
        "admin": {
            "username": "admin",
            "password": "pa55word",
            "tenant_name": "t1"
        },
        "users": [
            {
                "username": "n1",
                "password": "password",
                "user_domain_name": "Default",
                "project_name": "p1",
                "project_domain_name": "Default"
            },
            {
                "username": "n2",
                "password": "password",
                "user_domain_name": "Default",
                "project_name": "p2",
                "project_domain_name": "Default"
            }
        ]       
    }
}
```

Looked into jq but it seemed confusing. How this can be achieved using jq?

Comment: What have you tried ? Searched ? Tested ?

Comment: @Inian yes it needs to be expanded

Comment: @Gilles I was going through documentation as well as this link [link] https://gist.github.com/joar/776b7d176196592ed5d8 but the solution didnt work
[link] https://gist.github.com/joar/776b7d176196592ed5d8#gistcomment-3185021

Comment: @oguzismail: I was just thinking is there a way to achieve the same in jq. If it is not possible, I can still live with hard coding. I was just thinking for the solution to be feasible even if lets say `abc` changes to `xyz`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab `AUTH` and `REG` environment variables from `$ENV` preset variable and create fields using them, then add the resulting object to the first member of the input. E.g:

```
first(.[]) |= ( $ENV | {
    auth_url:      .AUTH,
    region_name:   .REG,
    endpoint_type: "PRIVATE"
  }
) + .
```

Comment: btw, does `env` work for exported variables also? The documentation says, `$ENV` is for environment variables (I guess ones `export`-ed) and `env` is for variables locally set in the shell environement

Comment: @Inian Took another look and, no, I can't see a difference between `env` and `$ENV` in 1.6. JQ doesn't (can't?) access variables local to shell, and it doesn't have a builtin for setting environment variables. So I guess `env` is reserved for future use.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach would be to take advantage of the fact that `+` on objects respects the ordering of keys:

```
.abc |= {auth_url: env.AUTH, region_name: env.REG, endpoint_type: "PRIVATE"} + .
```

This assumes that AUTH and REG are environment variables. If they are not, then you could use the --arg and/or --argjson command-line options, e.g.

```
jq --arg AUTH "$AUTH" --arg REG "$REG" '
   .abc |= {auth_url: $AUTH, region_name: $REG, endpoint_type: "PRIVATE"} + .
' sample.json
```